# photos.addTag returns "Invalid photo id"

Tags: facebook, api

Let me know what could be the problem when `photos.addTag` API always returns "Invalid photo id". I upload a photo and right after getting response I call the API with new photo's photo ID.

There is another app which uses same library which I can add tag without problem. I appreciate if someone can share the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The insert of data probably goes into one database and it takes time to be replicated to the other data stores.  The tag insert cannot find it because it hasn't had time to propage thru facebook's backend systems.  You will need to queue the message for taggin in your code for a length of time and then set up a queue reader that will process messages in the queue.  Also it might be nice to code for allowing a failed message to be retried.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was exactly as you said. I succeed with pictures which I uploaded before.

Comment: Excellent, glad to help! Personally I hate writing for queues, but sometimes that's the only right solution.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be an FB permissions related issue. I received the same error from the OG API using the PHP SDK. Requesting the `user_photos` extended permission resolved the issue for me.